# Load an animation image while running a function in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I want to load an animation image while running a function (like: loading....).
How can I do in iphone SDK?

Comment: Can you be more specific as the type of animation you are looking to perform? Is this an external animation (like a movie file) - or would an activity indicator or progress bar be sufficient?

Comment: I want to load a gif animation image while processing a function in background.

Answer (score 0):

Use CoreAmination.

```
self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(self.layer.transform, M_PI, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
animation.autoreverses = NO;
animation.duration = 1.00;
//animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"spinner"];
```